# Call boosts dijkstra shortest paths algorithm using a external weight map

Tags: c++, boost

I want to create a graph and call Dijkstra multiple times using different weight maps. I read that I can use an associative_property_map to map edges to weights but I don't know how to call Dijkstra using this custom map as a weight map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>


typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, 
                              boost::vecS, 
                              boost::undirectedS>
                                                                graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<graph>::edge_descriptor             edge_desc;
typedef boost::graph_traits<graph>::vertex_descriptor          vertex_desc;
typedef std::map<edge_desc, boost::edge_weight_t>               edge_weight_map;                 
typedef boost::associative_property_map<edge_weight_map>        weight_map; 

void dijkstra_path(const graph &G, const weight_map &w_map, int s, int t, std::vector<vertex_desc> &pred_map) {
  int n = boost::num_vertices(G);
  std::vector<int>         dist_map(n);
  
  boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(G, s,
    boost::distance_map(
      boost::make_iterator_property_map(dist_map.begin(), boost::get(boost::vertex_index, G)))
      .predecessor_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(pred_map.begin(), boost::get(boost::vertex_index, G))),
      w_map);

}
```

This is how I imagined it to work, can anybody tell me how to actually do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing positional parameters with named parameters. The overload with named parameters doesn't take a weightmap positional: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html

So, add the weight map to the name parameters:

```
using graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>;
using edge_desc       = boost::graph_traits<graph>::edge_descriptor;
using vertex_desc     = boost::graph_traits<graph>::vertex_descriptor;
using edge_weight_map = std::map<edge_desc, boost::edge_weight_t>;
using weight_map      = boost::associative_property_map<edge_weight_map>;

void dijkstra_path(const graph& G, weight_map w_map, int s, int /*t*/,
                   std::vector<vertex_desc>& pred_map) //
{
    int              n = boost::num_vertices(G);
    std::vector<int> dist_map(n);

    auto id = get(boost::vertex_index, G);
    auto dm = make_iterator_property_map(dist_map.begin(), id);
    auto pm = make_iterator_property_map(pred_map.begin(), id);

    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths( //
        G, s,                       //
        boost::distance_map(dm)     //
            .predecessor_map(pm)    //
            .weight_map(w_map));
}
```

As a general tip, pass property maps by value. They're lightweight "reference" types designed to be very cheap to copy.